# How can I set TextBoxFor to be hidden by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

I have a view in MVC3 with a TextBoxFor bound to my model like so:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

How could I change this to be a textbox which would have style="display: none;" by default?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by default, but you could add the style attribute:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { style = "display: none;" }) %>
```

or:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { @class = "hidden" }) %>
```

and in your CSS file:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be any harder then that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { @readonly = "readonly", @hidden="true"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.SomeProperty, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```